# Invert an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm filtering a given *Array* using its native `.filter()` method:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

var b = a.filter(function(v) {
    return v > 2;
});
```

That creates the new Array (`[3,4,5]`). Now, I also want to have the filtered values in another array. What is my best option here? Should I

- push the removed values into a new array **within** that same filter method ?
- write an invert function and apply it after filtering ?

To go with the first option, it might end up this:

```
var b = a.filter(function(v) {
    return v > 2 || !c.push(v);
});
```

My problem with that solution is, that it kinda mixes two different things and maybe very confusing for anybody who reads the code in the future. As an alternative, I could call something like

```
c = invert(a,b);

function invert(source, compare) {
    return source.filter(filterPositives);

    function filterPositives(v) {
        return compare.indexOf(v) === -1;
    };
}
```

Is that effective? Or can I do better ?

Any other (more elegant) ideas how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think going through the source array twice is an elegant solution. But then again, adding side-effects to your own `filter` is not great either.

I'd solve the problem by writing a `filterSplit` function, something like this pseudocode:

```
function filterSplit(
      Array source, Array positives, Array negatives, Function filterCb) 
{
  source.forEach(function(el) {
    if (filterCb(el)) {
      positives.push(el); 
    }
    else {
      negatives.push(el);
    }
  }
}
```

... or, if you'd prefer arrays in your return ...

```
function anotherFilterSplit(Array source, Function filterCb) {
  var positives = [], negatives = [];
  // ... the same check and push as above ...
  return [positives, negatives];
}
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty elegant solution (though I suppose not having to pass in two empty (or not-empty) arrays would be more in line with `filter`).

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I don't think I can use that really. I need to loop loop over the source array to actually *create* the negative values. So I would end up looping twice again wouldn't I ?

Comment: @AndreMeinhold Can you update your question with examples of source array, expected positives and negatives then?

Comment: @raina77ow: its all there. I'm filtering an array with a condition, which creates a new filtered array. So the "rest" of that filter should become another new array. So first loop (filter), second loop( find rest and push)

Comment: Since when does JavaScript have typed arguments?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5],b=[],c=[];

for(var i=0,l=a.length,ai=a[i];i<l;ai=a[++i])
    if(ai>2)b.push(ai);
    else c.push(ai);

console.log(b,c);
// [3, 4, 5]   [1, 2]
```

Comment: One of my concerns (as stated) was the readabilty and convinience for other people. I don't think this would help much :)

Comment: Why? One `for` lop, one `if` statement. All other is speed optimization and can be removed.

Comment: looks better now. when I wrote that comment you had it all one-lined.

Comment: @Andre Meinhold, _"all one-lined"_ - sorry, is my style, but this does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

@raina77ow 's solution looks good. For the heck of it, here's an implementation in [Coco](http://github.com/satyr/coco):

```
function filterSplit (source, predicate, positives = [], negatives = [])
  source.forEach -> (if predicate it then positives else negatives).push el
  return [positives, negatives]
```

and the compiled JavaScript

```
function filterSplit(source, predicate, positives, negatives){
  positives == null && (positives = []);
  negatives == null && (negatives = []);
  source.forEach(function(it){
    return (predicate(it) ? positives : negatives).push(el);
  });
  return [positives, negatives];
}
```

-- so you can either pass in your `positives` and `negatives`, or leave them unpassed in which case you'll get new empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since Andrew D. already written a good answer I'm not sure if I should write this but:

http://jsfiddle.net/BsJFv/2/

```
Array.prototype.divide = function(fun, neg) {
    if (this == null) throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();

    if (!(neg instanceof Array)) {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    neg.splice(0, neg.length);
    var thisp = arguments[2];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            var val = t[i];
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t)) {
                res.push(val);
            }
            else {
                neg.push(val);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
};
```

This way you got a nice divide function.

First parameter is the function you want to divide on, the second parameter is the array for negative values.

Only limitation is that you must instantiate the second parameter as an array before the call:

```
var negatives = [];
var positives = x.divide(function(elem) {
    /* whatever you want to check */
}, negatives);
```